# Angular NgRx Getting information from API

Tags: angular, typescript, api, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm trying to put the information that comes from the api when doing an omdb search and put it in the scope of NgRx in angular 13.

below is the code of which I am trying to insert the scope but it accuses the error
"Type 'Movie' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Movie[]>': source, operator, lift, subscribe, and 3 more."

```
export class MovieSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  
  movies$: Observable<Movie[]>;
  Title = new FormControl;

  constructor(private movieService: MovieService, private store: Store<MovieState>) { 
    this.movies$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectMovies));
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getMovie(): void {

    this.movieService.getMovie(this.Title.value).subscribe(
      movie => {
        this.movies$ = movie
      }
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Where are you actually reducing this in the store?

Comment: You have problem with types. This is not related with ngrx. You are gettting this error because you have movies$ observable of movie arrays, you are trying to assign a single movie which has type of Movie.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue should be in this line

```
this.movies$ = movie
```

the type of this.movies$ is Observable<Movie[]>, an observable that emits an array of Movie values.

In your observer function, your are trying to assign the "movie" value, that is of Movie type, so they are incompatible.

To solve this issue, just declare the movie property ad use it in your observer, instead of movies$

```
public movie: Movie
[...]
this.movie = movie
```

Comment: In this case I'm not able to use NgRx

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the below code

```
getMovie(): void {
    this.movies$ = this.movieService.getMovie(this.Title.value)
  }
```

and you must return Movie array from your service file.